# Angular ViewChildren returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, viewchildren

I've gone through quite a few other questions on SO related to this Angular feature and none of the solutions seem to help my scenario. I'm utilizing the [Angular Material tree component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview), and am attempting to generate a component within a fully expanded node.

My `Tree.component.html`:

```
<ng-container class="tree-content">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
                <ng-container *ngIf="node.expandable">
                    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name" (click)="generateTreeContent(node, treeControl.isExpanded(node))">
                        <mat-icon class="dark">
                        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <p>{{node.name}}</p>
                </ng-container>
                <app-dynamic></app-dynamic>
            </mat-tree-node>
        </mat-tree>
    </mat-card>
</ng-container>
```

My `ViewChildren` decorator declaration in `Tree.component.ts`:

```
@ViewChildren(DynamicComponent) children: QueryList<DynamicComponent>;
```

My `Dynamic.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dynamic',
    templateUrl: './Dynamic.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./Dynamic.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public ref: ElementRef) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Every time I try to access `children`, the `QueryList` yields no results.

## **Other things I've tried:**

- Using the 'read' metadata property:

  `*.ts`:

  ```
  @ViewChildren('dynamic', { read: DynamicComponent }) children: QueryList<DynamicComponent>;
  ```

  `*.html`:

  ```
  <app-dynamic #dynamic></app-dynamic>
  ```
- Subscribing to the `QueryList` changes via `AfterViewInit()`:

  ```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
      this.children.changes.subscribe((c: QueryList<DynamicComponent>) =>
      {
        ...
      });
  }
  ```
- Using `ContentChildren` (Both with and without the 'read' parameter):

  `*.ts`:

  ```
  @ContentChildren('dynamic', { read: DynamicComponent }) children: QueryList<DynamicComponent>;
  ```

  `*.html`:

  ```
  <app-dynamic #dynamic></app-dynamic>
  ```
- Accessing the component via Directive:

  ```
  @ViewChildren('dynamic', { read: DynamicDirective }) children: QueryList<DynamicDirective>;
  ```
- Accessing after forcing change detection:

  ```
  this.viewContainerRef.detectChanges();
  console.log(this.children.toArray());
  ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your `Tree.component.ts` when are you trying to access the children? You cannot access them in `ngOnInit()` it will be `undefined` at that point.

Comment: I'm attempting to access the children in the generateTreeContent function called in the (click) defined in the html. And I've also tried in the change subscription of the children property, which should update with every change.

Comment: I assume that `<app-dynamic>` is in the inspector is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I can see the tag in the inspector.

Comment: When you subscribe to changes, do you ever get the subscription to execute? Even if you expand the tree?

Comment: it's looks like work well, I've wrote an example in stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-91kw8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.html (What about your function `generateTreeContent`?